# Custom Keyboard for emoticons in android

Tags: android, keyboard, emoticons

I want to use a custom keyboard of emoticons and default keyboard for my chatting application. For writing a message user can switch between these two keyboards.

What is the best way to implement this functionality in android ?

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768930/implementations-of-emoji-emoticon-view-keyboard-layouts